# Query Count Rows Join Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I've been struggling trying to do this query, this is what I have/need:

Two tables, Table A and Table B, for each row in table A there might be N rows in table B. But I need to find the rows from A that have exactly two rows in B where one of them the type( column in B) starts with 'PYT' and the other one has a column null, also I need the amount from table B to be from the latest row( DATEP in table B)  I've been trying to do it, but I've found some issues, this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    A.TYPE, A.NMRAD,A.ID,  B.AMOUNT
FROM
    TABLE_A A
    JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.ID = B.ID_A    AND A.NMRAD = B.NMRAD  AND A.TYPE = B.TYPE
WHERE
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID_A = A.ID AND TYPE LIKE 'PYT%'
    UNION 
    SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID_A = A.ID AND B.TYPEPROCESS IS NOT NULL))=2
    WHERE A.TYPE=?
```

For example:

```
Table A
ID   | NMRAD  | TYPE 
1    |   2    |  PYT1
2    |   14   |  PYT2
5    |   11   |  PYY2

TABLE B
ID_A | NMRAD | TYPE | TYPEPROCESS | AMOUNT | DATEP
1    |  2    | PTY1 | NULL        |  50    | 18/10/2018
1    |  2    | PYY2 | 123         |  35    | 19/10/2018
2    |  14   | PTY2 | NULL        |  50    | 18/09/2018
2    |  14   | PTY2 | NULL        |  35    | 17/10/2018
2    |  14   | PTY3 | NULL        |  77    | 11/07/2018

EXPECTED RESULT

TYPE | NMRAD | ID | AMOUNT 
PTY1 | 2     | 1  |  35
```

Comment: sample data and the expected result please.

Comment: Done, I just added the sample data and the result I'd be expecting

Comment: What do you mean with "registers"? Rows?

Comment: yes, I do , I'm going  to change so it can be understood better, thanks

Comment: At one place you show `PYT` and another place it's `PTY`, which one do you use? You said *...one of them the type( column in B) starts with PYT and the other one has a column null* - Do you mean `TYPE like PTY%`  and one of the `TYPEPROCESS` is `NULL` and other is any  number (123) ?

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong, it's PTY, basically I need to get only the ones that has two rows where one starts with 'PTY' TYPE like PTY% and the other has TYPEPROCESS NULL, and also I need the amount from table B that corresponds with the latest DATEP

Answer (score 0):

I could not match your "exactly two rows" criteria, but here is SQL that matches your expected results:

```
WITH
    aset AS
        (SELECT a.*
           FROM tablea a
          WHERE     EXISTS
                        (SELECT NULL
                           FROM tableb b
                          WHERE     a.id = b.id
                                AND a.nmrad = b.nmrad
                                AND a.TYPE = b.TYPE
                                AND b.TYPE LIKE 'PTY%')
                AND EXISTS
                        (SELECT NULL
                           FROM tableb b
                          WHERE     a.id = b.id
                                AND a.nmrad = b.nmrad
                                AND a.TYPE = b.TYPE
                                AND b.typeprocess IS NULL))
SELECT a.*
     , (SELECT amount
          FROM tableb b
         WHERE     a.id = b.id
               AND a.nmrad = b.nmrad
               AND datep = (SELECT MAX( datep )
                              FROM tableb bb
                             WHERE b.id = bb.id AND b.nmrad = bb.nmrad))    amount
  FROM aset a;
```

This resulted in:

```
ID     NMRAD     TYPE     AMOUNT
 1         2     PTY1         35
```

Make it easy for us to help you, next time include a setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tablea
(
    id       NUMBER( 3 )
  , nmrad    NUMBER( 2 )
  , TYPE     VARCHAR2( 4 )
);

CREATE TABLE tableb
(
    id             NUMBER( 3 )
  , nmrad          NUMBER( 2 )
  , TYPE           VARCHAR2( 4 )
  , typeprocess    NUMBER( 3 )
  , amount         NUMBER( 3 )
  , datep          DATE
);

begin
  insert into tablea values (1,   2,  'PTY1');
  insert into tablea values (2,   14,  'PTY1');
  insert into tablea values (5,   11,  'PTY1');

  insert into tableb values (1,  2, 'PTY1', NULL,  50, to_date('18/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  insert into tableb values (1,  2, 'PYY2', 123,   35, to_date('19/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  insert into tableb values (2,  14, 'PTY2', NULL, 50, to_date('18/09/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  insert into tableb values (2,  14, 'PTY2', NULL, 35, to_date('17/10/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  insert into tableb values (2,  14, 'PTY3', NULL, 77, to_date('11/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));
  commit;
end;
```

Comment: It can be done using **single** join and a `group by` in inline view.